# Getting custom files to launch like .exe in Windows

Tags: python, operating-system, filesystems, exe

How does Windows know that an .exe application is an .exe application. Also, how would you tell windows to send this type of application to this program, that you have created. Like how Python programs are .py and are text files, but when you click on it, it acts like an executable. Or is it the other way around? I don't know. Any type of help would be useful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows this is different.
There is a variable called PATHEXT in the environment, like this
`PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY`
Notice that I've added the `.py` extension to mark python scripts to be executable. That is the first step.
Then, you need to tell Windows which program will run this script. For that, you have the `assoc` and `ftype` commands.
When you type `assoc` you get the list of known file extensions. Here, I get `.py=Python.File` as output. Now you have to connect this extension to a program, ie. the python executable python.exe. Do this with `ftype`:

```
D:\\>ftype Python.File
Python.File="C:\Program Files (x86)\python27\python.exe" "%1" %*
```

I think that the correct calls to `assoc` and `ftype` are done when installing python. Then you only have to append the extension to PATHEXT.

Answer (score 0):

A `.py` file *doesn't* execute when you write `$ ./file.py` unless you add `#!/usr/bin/env python` or `C:\\Python27\python.exe` something like that at the very beginning of it. The OS tries to execute the following: `the_thing_you_wrote_after_# file.py` If you change the extension to `.lold` it will work too.

If you try to do `./file.py` without adding the line I was talking about earlier, the current shell'll try to parse the text and will definitely give errors.

I'm not quite sure, but Windows checks if it's possible to run a file by checking its extension first. It also searches for the entry point. If you rename your `test.exe` to `test.test` it won't work.

You can't launch a `.py` file like an app unless you use special tools like *py2exe* and *cxfreeze*.

Comment: How does Windows know where to send the .py file to be complied?

Comment: Do you think it would take some cmd to accomplished the task?

Comment: I would have to somehow tell Windows to send my file extension to an exe, which I have made, to handle it?

Comment: @TristanFrye, you cannot _send your file extension to an exe_, you have to use some tools for it.